# Is there an advantage in using continued fractions for Catalan or Fibonacci-Lucas primality tests?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, continued-fractions, catalan-numbers, primality-test

I am studying the basic theory about [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) and also reviewed here at MSE former questions to learn more. While reviewing the questions and answers, I found references to the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and their continued fractions, so I wondered if there was some special advantage on using continued fractions for Fibonacci-Lucas ($F_n$) or Catalan ($C_n$) primality testing (or at least if there is a different new point view of the primality of a number). In other words:

> Is there an advantage on testing the pattern of the continued fraction of $\frac{C_n}{n}$ instead of testing the values of ($C_n$ mod $n$)?

In the past I made a [two steps primality test (link)](http://hobbymaths.blogspot.jp/2015/02/fibonacci-catalan-deterministic-prime.html) based on a shifted version of [Catalan numbers](http://oeis.org/A000108) (for each odd $n$, instead of using $C_n$, testing the residues of $C_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$) and Fibonacci numbers (to verify that the pseudoprimes of the Fibonacci and Catalan primality tests are disjoint sets), both steps based on the residues of $F_n$ and $C_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$ mod $n$.

Instead of studying the residues now I wanted to know how the continued fraction of $\frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}}{n}$ looks like, so I did the exercise and observed that there are two families of prime numbers ($\forall p \in \Bbb P \gt 7$), following the patterns:

> $p_i \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{p_i}{2}\rfloor}}{p_i}=[b_i;3,k_i,l_i]\ \ \ \{b_i,k_i,l_i\} \gt 0 \in \Bbb N\ $ and $\ (k_i+l_i) \lt (k_j+l_j)\ \forall\ p_j \gt p_i$ (same pattern).
>
> $p_m \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{p_m}{2}\rfloor}}{p_m}=[b_m;4,k_m]\ \ \ \{b_m,k_m\} \gt 0 \in \Bbb N\ $ and $\ k_m \lt k_r\ \forall\ p_r \gt p_m$ (same pattern).
>
> ... where $[a;b,c..,z]$ is the usual [notation for continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Motivation_and_notation).

E.g.:

> Examples of $p_i=[b_i;3,k_i,l_i]$:
>
> $19 \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{19}{2}\rfloor}}{19}=[75;3,1,4]$, and $\sum\{1,4\}=5$
>
> $23 \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{23}{2}\rfloor}}{23}=[730;3,1,5]$, and $\sum\{1,5\}=6$
>
> $31 \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{31}{2}\rfloor}}{31}=[86272;3,1,7]$, and $\sum\{1,7\}=8$
>
> Examples of $p_m=[b_m;4,k_m]$:
>
> $37 \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{37}{2}\rfloor}}{37}=[3503913;4,9]$, and $k_{37}=9$
>
> $53 \to \frac{C_{\lfloor \frac{53}{2}\rfloor}}{53}=[91734837763;4,13]$, and $k_{53}=13$

When I tested this with Python, I was very happy to observe that it works like the standard Catalan primality test ($\forall p \in \Bbb P \gt 7$), including exactly the primes and the [Catalan pseudoprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_pseudoprime) only (the first one is $5907$ [OEIS A163209](https://oeis.org/A163209)). So it seems that verifying the patterns above in the continued fractions is equivalent to a standard primality test based on the residues of the Catalan numbers.

Here is the Python code:

```
def frac():
    from gmpy2 import is_prime, mul, divexact, fac, add, c_mod, xmpz, sub

    def makefrac(vara,varb):

        a = vara
        b = varb

        mf = []

        while c_mod(a,b)!=0:
            mf.append(a//b)
            newa = add(a,-mul(a//b,b))
            temp = b
            b = newa
            a = temp

        mf.append(a//b)

        return mf

    test_init, test_limit = xmpz(9), xmpz(10000)
    catalan_number,divisible_four  = xmpz(1),True

    sumcheckl = 0
    sumchecks = 0
    for n in range (test_init,test_limit,2):

        catalan_number = divexact(mul(catalan_number, sub(n,4)), xmpz(n)>>2) if divisible_four else divexact(mul(catalan_number, sub(n,4)), xmpz(n)>>1)<<1
        divisible_four = not divisible_four

        myf = makefrac(catalan_number,n)        

        if ((len(myf)==4) and (myf[1]==3)) or ((len(myf)==3) and (myf[1]==4)):
            mysum = 0           
            if (len(myf)==4):
                mysum = myf[2]+myf[3]
                if sumcheckl == 0:
                    sumcheckl = mysum
                elif mysum < sumcheckl:
                    continue
                else:
                    sumcheckl = mysum
            else:
                mysum = myf[2]
                if sumchecks == 0:
                    sumchecks = mysum
                elif mysum < sumchecks:
                    continue
                else:
                    sumchecks = mysum

            if is_prime(n):
                print("Prime found: " + str(n)+"\t" + str(mysum))
            else:
                print("Pseudoprime found: " + str(n)+"\t" + str(mysum))

frac()
```

I do not understand the theory behind these observations, so please I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Is it possible to know why the specific pattern of the continued fraction implies the same result as the Catalan primality test over the residues of the number?
> 2. Could this approach be an advantage versus studying the primality of a number via residues like in Catalan and Fibonacci-Lucas primality tests? (could it be another way of defining the primality test?)

Please let me know if there are errors in the calculations or assumptions and I will update the question. Any hints are very welcomed. Thank you!